# Multistore (languages) on one and the same domain (no subdirectories or subdomains)

Tags: multistore, localisation, language, internationalization

we have several stores. All with several languages. Now I was wondering why we dont just serve all these stores using 1 domain? (no storecode, no subdirectory)

**Question:** Why would this not be an idea?

Suppose one could add the href lang tag. Based on the accept language customers are sent to the relevant store (using __store variable in URL/that we hide using apache)
[href lang tag](http://www.magmodules.eu/alternate-hreflang.html)

---

The options for a multistore are as follows

**Add storecode to URL** The most basic option is to be found under System > Configuration > Web called the option Add storecode to url. The drawback is however that this will also affect the existing stores adding the storecode to that one's urls as well (but there is an extension to circumvent this for default store)
[hide default store code](https://github.com/jreinke/magento-hide-default-store-code)

**Create a subdirectory** You will need to create a subdirectory in your Magento installations root called /storename and copy the index.php in there. Also create symlinks for the media, js and skins directory and add an .htaccess (you can copy that one from the root, if you use apache)

**Work with subdomains** In this case that would be newstore.domain.com. Just add this to you apache config and set the new storeviews base domain to that URL

**New! Stay on the same domain.** In this case you just set-up the new store. Don't change the store URL's. The language dropdown appears. In this you should use a multilanguage sitemap + href lang tags.