# Multistore on single domain without subdomains or subfolders, perhaps using cookies

Tags: multistore

We currently have multiple websites and stores (store views) in order to support multiple base currencies and languages. We have a seperate subfolder for each website.

Is it possible to do away with the subfolders and have the current store stored in a cookie? This would appear to the user in much the same way switching languages works; you don't see the store view code in the URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grabbing storeview from cookie (after using language selector)](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64666/grabbing-storeview-from-cookie-after-using-language-selector)

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of related questions like this one.
Have you seen this one?
[Multistore (languages) on one and the same domain (no subdirectories or subdomains)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58349/multistore-languages-on-one-and-the-same-domain-no-subdirectories-or-subdomai?rq=1)

and the link to hide store code URL:
https://github.com/jreinke/magento-hide-default-store-code

Comment: I'm afraid neither of these are helpful. Currently the $mageRunCode is set by the index.php in each subfolder. I'm looking for a way to avoid subfolders alltogether and have the $mageRunCode set by cookie. A switcher along the line of the language switcher would then support changing websites.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the same base url for all stores and Magento already stores the current store id in a cookie.

For stores within a website there is already a store (language) switcher built in, now the only thing missing is a way to switch to stores of a different website. The links can be constructed in the same way: `___store=X&___from_store=Y`.

So what you have to do is create a modified version of the store switcher template and block that loads all stores instead of just the stores of the current website.